# Drawing bar graphs with AChartEngine Android

Tags: java, android, graphics, achartengine, bar-chart

```
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class BarGraph {
public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    int[] y = { 111, 201, 9, 876, 123 };

    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Survey Result Graphs");

    for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        series.add("Bar " + (i+1), y[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 0.5);
    renderer.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Survey Results");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("X Values");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y Values");

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

    return intent;
}
```

}

I am using the above code to draw a bar graph and testing it on my phone. This has been completely picked up from a video tutorial. However, whenever this activity is called upon a click event (in another activity), a blank white screen and absolutely no graph shows up. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you look at the AChartEngine official demo.

Answer (score 0):

use getBarChartView function instead of getBarChartIntent